# How to correctly use securityfilterchain in spring security 6?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on the below spring security conf but the security filter chain is full of deprecated methods. What is the way to correctly decompose it and use not deprecated methods?

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/v1/**", "/v2/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs/**")
                .permitAll().requestMatchers("/v3/polls/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic()
                .realmName("Quick Poll").and().csrf().disable().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: by upgrading to spring security 6

Comment: sorry I ment 6. Already using it.

Comment: then i suggest you read the official documentation on how to implement whatever it is you are going to implement and stop following outdated blogs which im guessing you are doing.